# Is it possible to send data to the the shell of another pseudo-terminal?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

This image shows how pseudo-terminals work:

[image]

If I have two terminal emulators open, I can send the string `"Hello"` from the first terminal emulator to the second terminal emulator:

```
echo "Hello" > /dev/pts/1
```

When this command is executed, the string `"Hello"` will travel from the slave side of the second pseudo-terminal to the master side of the second pseudo-terminal and then gets displayed on the second terminal emulator.

Now is it possible to send data in the opposite direction, that is, to send data to the shell instead of the terminal emulator (or the process that the shell is running)?

Comment: The TIOCSTI ioctl might be relevant (assuming you have root or the appropriate capability set)...

Comment: I think this question has been asked several times (can't find them ATM), and so answer so far has been "no easy way to fake input to the shell".

Comment: Are you trying to run *commands* in the other terminal, or just dump text data there?  The [write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_(Unix)), [talk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk_(software)), and [wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_(Unix)) (as in "write to all") command line programs can do that.

Answer (score 1):

It might not exactly be what you are looking for, but these kind of problems I usually solve by running screen sessions in my terminals.

I do it like this:

- In terminal 1 I start a new screen session called *term1* with `screen -S term1`
  Often when I need this functionality terminal 1 doesn't exist yet. In that case I create the session in a new terminal with `xterm -e screen -S term1 & ; disown`
  *You might be wondering about the `& ; disown`. This is because I want the shell back after xterm has launched and I don't want `xterm` to die if the shell where I launched it dies*
- I do something similar in the 2nd terminal: `screen -S term2` (or create a new terminal by running `xterm -e screen -S term2 & ; disown`)
- Communication now works as follows:

  - You can send text to the 1st terminal from everywhere (including terminal 2) with a command like:
    `screen -S term1 -X stuff 'echo "foo"\n'`
    The result would be the same as entering `echo "foo"` at the 1st terminal and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>
  - Easier example: to send the input `some words` but *not* following it by <kbd>Enter</kbd> to terminal 2 you can use `screen -S term2 -X stuff 'some words'`

Sidenotes:

- If you already had screen sessions named `term1` and/or `term2` use other names
- If you ran `screen -S somename` in a already existing terminal note that only the screen session is killed after running `exit`.
  If you want the whole terminal to stop then use `screen -S somename ; exit` instead.
  This is not necessary in newly created terminals.

Comment: Note that running screen or tmux sessions in your terminals is _almost always_ a good idea. For me the most important 3 reasons are the possibilities to: (de/re)-attach sessions, use multiple windows in 1 session, share sessions. Both tmux, screen and their frontends (e.g. byobu) also have a gigantic amount of other features. Check the manpages.

Answer (score 0):

TIOCSTI works as said in a comment by [thrig](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/128228/thrig) above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29615101/2995591

Answer (score -1):

Each proccess has 3 default "file descriptors"

```
0 is stdin  (standart input)
1 is stdout (standart output)
2 is stderr (standart error output)
```

You need to find PID of shell process and then you can do following:

```
echo "test" > /proc/{your_shell_pid}/fd/1
```

This will print test in the shell process' standart output